# Jet error 3011 when opening a file with 2 "extensions"

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao, jet

I'm having a problem with Jet throwing error 3011 when I try to use it to open a file with 2 "extensions" ("filename.tst.csv").

> Run-time error '3011'
>
> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'filename.tst.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Where the code looks like this:

```
Dim db as Database, rs as Recordset
Set db = OpenDatabase("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & fileName & "];")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & fileName & "];")
```

I've tracked down the problem to be the second extension (or apparent extension) ".tst" but I'm not sure why the error is occurring and I haven't been able to find an answer through Google or through here - but I figure someone might have some insight as to the limitations.

This is using DAO 3.6 in VB6.

Comment: There's a bug in my code above - I won't be into work until next Wednesday but I resolved the error with a different work around (just opening the recordset on the file and using the first row - same thing essentially). I'll post the actual answer and fix the above code with what is actually there when I get back to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly the situation you're talking about, but in reading this, in the CAUSE section, the information about some drivers not supporting long filenames looks like it  would apply, since this is not in an 8.3 format.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=3011&ac=8

So, you'd need to rename the file OR use another method to load the data (such as using a StreamReader).  Personally, I'd rename the file.  It'd be much easier.

Comment: Technically not the solution I was looking for but seems to provide a reason as to why this is failing, or at least the best hint I could find as to why it fails.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hackey, but you could programatically rename the file before opening it to a more friendly extension. Just keep the old extension around so you can set it back when you are done.

Comment: Yea that's probably the solution I'll go with if I can't find a better one - it's just for import (copying into an internal format) so I'd just copy it to a temp folder with a better file name.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the short file name instead? It won't contain more than one period. Just drop in the CFileInfo class from [this](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FileInfo/) offering from Karl E Peterson's excellent site (it has a wrapper method for the [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(VS.85).aspx) API call).

I suppose the volume might not support short file names (it's [optional](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210638)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a schema.ini file for your import file, or add the extension to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\Format registry key so ADO knows how to parse the file. There is a detailed explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

Comment: Schema.ini is already created - that's not the problem. Also I'm not using ADO I'm using DAO.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the DAO. I jumped in because I had this issue a few years ago importing a CSV file with an oddball extension to a VFP table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about this because I haven't used DAO much since it became obsolete in VB6.  I know that Jet's rules can be very different going between the OLE DB Provider, ODBC Driver, and DAO.

Have you tried replacing the "." characters in those file names by "#" characters?  Or maybe just the last one?  Just in your SQL statement text.

Comment: I too thought of this but when I tried it didn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your second line of code cannot return anything!

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & fileName & "];")
```

You cannot open a database with a SELECT instruction! Your code shouls look like

```
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(filenamne)
```